# How do i change an element of a struct over a struct in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char Name[100];

typedef struct Daughter
{
    Name name;
    int age;
    int height;
}Tochter;

typedef struct Father
{
    Tochter kleine[6];
    Name v;
    int age;
    int height;
    int numofdaugh;
}Dad;

int main (void)
{
    Vater Martin, *pDad;
    int numofdau;
    printf("How many Daughters? ");
    scanf("%i", Martin.numofdaugh);

    pDad = &Martin;
    pDad->kleine[0].name = "Alice"; 
    // I also tried Martin.kleine[0].name = "Alice";
}
```

I also tried to change elements with functions but it still didnt work and the error msg is:
"expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type "Tochter".

Comment: @Botje `kleine` is an array of `Tochter`.

Comment: @Botje Now I see that that was changed in an edit around the same time you posted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. you cant assign arrays.
2. scanf requires pointer,.

```
    scanf("%i", &Martin.numofdaugh);

    pDad = &Martin;
    strcpy(pDad->kleine[0].name, "Alice");
```

PS Type `Dad` should be `Vater`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` needs to be passed a pointer.

Rather than:

```
scanf("%i", Martin.numofdaugh);
```

Pass a pointer to `Martin.numofdaugh`:

```
scanf("%i", &Martin.numofdaugh);
```

You also want to use [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) to copy a string into a `Name`.

```
Name bobs_name = {0};
strncpy(bobs_name, "Bob", 100);
```

Using `strncpy` rather than `strcpy` prevents the possibility of an overflow, as a `Name` is limited to 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
pDad->kleine[0].name = "Alice";
```

is wrong because you can't copy C-strings this way (use `strcpy`).

More correct is:

```
strcpy(pDad->kleine[0].name,"Alice");
```

Comment: @barmar A weird edit as been made in the meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

@Chris answer is correct, but you also have a Type `Vater` that does not exist elsewhere.